# HTML5 with PHP and fluid grid layouts

Tags: php, html, grid, dreamweaver

I recently got dreamweaver cs6 for it's newest upgrade of fluid grid layouts. I am excited to learn about HTML5, but haven't just yet. I have however noticed that html5 cannot have php coding in it. Is there a way to enable it? I use php quite a lot, and was just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP runs on the server. HTML is a markup language parsed by the browser (client). You don't "enable" PHP for HTMl5, you run it on your server and it spits out whatever you want it to. If that happens to be HTML5, then if the browser supports it you'll get a page.

You can just write PHP as you would with an HTML 4.01; it's only the client that will see a difference. To the server, it's "all just strings".

Comment: So in other words, I can not use <?php echo "blah" ?> within my pages anymore, for that matter require_once? Perhaps I should study html5 more before I dive in!

Comment: Are you sure you know what HTML5 is? Of course you can use `<?php echo "blah" ?>` in an HTML5 page - the server will still execute it as PHP. If your editor isn't syntax highlighting PHP in HTML, change the file extension to `.php` and it should work.

Comment: The reason I'm asking in the first place is that in my code editor, the <?php doesn't turn red anymore

Comment: Ok, thanks. Not sure if you are familiar with DW CS6, but It doesn't offer the .php extension for their new fluid grid layout system. I could try to amend the extension after it's made, will just have to try I suppose :)